# Hibernate Envers - get revisions and objects between dates

Tags: java, hibernate, audit, hibernate-envers

Consider a Car that has contracts, amendments, maintenance, dealers etc... 
When there is an update in a contract one will find a **revision_id** and a **revision_timestemp** and if you go to the contract_aud you can find by the reivsion_id the new version.

My goal is to provide the end user a query where he can ask: what **cars** (plural) had revisions between startDate and endDate. Note that the revision can be in contract/maintenance/dealer etc...(and I only cares about the car's IDs)

From what I have today, one can query by date in the following manner:

```
    AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(em);
    AuditQuery q = auditReader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(Car.class, false, true);
    q.add(AuditEntity.revisionProperty("timestamp").ge(startDate.getTime()));
    q.add(AuditEntity.revisionProperty("timestamp").lt(endDate.getTime()));
```

But you can note that I send the **Car.class** and if the revision was made in the '**contract**' I will have to send the Contract.class (and later get the car's ID)

I have 20+ tables with postfix _AUD so it makes no sense to go 20 times to the db.

Question: how can one query for revision that happen between dates and the revision number and the **object** that was changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the  `@ModifiedEntityNames` annotation in your revision entity.

This [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/envers/Envers.html) has some details (it's not indexed, search for the annotation, you'll find it.)

Using the annotation is not so simple, because it changes the revision entity you are using (even if it's the provided default or any custom made).

It will create a collection associated with each revision, and in this collection will contain the entity names that were changed in the related revision.

With that in hand, you can query for revisions in a given time window, and the tables that were changed. Later you can use the revision timestamp to get each entity changed in the transaction.

If you are still in development then it will surely help, but if you have a production running system, then will only be useful for future changes.

Answer (score 0):

A classic approach is to write a simple SQL statement with left join that provides the date and the revision for each table. The objective is solely to receive the CAR id's without any revision interpretations.

```
SELECT ri.revision_id, ri.revision_timestamp, s.id supplier_id ...
from revinfo as ri 
left join ...
left join... 
where ri.revision_timestamp 
between 1546530449341 and 1546532280293
```

Occam's razor ;-)